# jquery get element position, offset() wrong values

Tags: jquery, window, offset

Jquery DOC says offset() relative to documents, and I saw many posts use it that way. Actually it is wrong.

```
#foo {
  position:relative;
}

#bar {
  position:absolute;
  left:16;
  right:16;
}

<div id="foo">

    <div id="bar"> 

    <div>
</div>

var fooOffset= $("#foo").offset();
var barOffset= $("#bar").offset();
```

The results are in Chrome:

```
foo offset: 300, 280;
bar offset: 0, 100
```

The foo offset is correct, relative to document.
but bar offset (0, 100)?  where does it come from?
If it is relative to positional parent, it should be (16, 16).
If it is relative to document, it should be (300 + 16, 280 + 16).

Can any help me figure out? What I am trying to do is to figure out the position relative to window like:

```
var y = $("#bar").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Working fine for me [here](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/xwaayL08/). Can you update the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/xwaayL08/) showing your problem?

Comment: I was not able to save changes on the fiddle. Updated but not saved on the fiddle server. The bar position is wrong. It say (8, 8), but should be (8 + 16, 8 + 16) relative to document. Thanks.

Comment: I post an answer explaining what is happening here :)

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the `left` and `right` properties without units (`px`, `%`, etc.). So:

```
#bar {
  position:absolute;
  left:16;
  right:16;
}
```

Should be:

```
#bar {
  position:absolute;
  left:16px;
  right:16px;
}
```

Check [this DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/xwaayL08/12/).

Note: I define a `width`, `height` and `border` so you can see what is happening. Also the `right` property does not have any effect because you are defining a `left` too. Maybe you want `top` instead `right` ;)